# Firebase tech support dashboard - how do I view responses?

Tags: firebase

I asked [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) a question and I don't know how to view their reply. It's listed there and says 'Awaiting your reply' but there's nowhere I can click to view the message and I didn't get any email.

[image]

Comment: Any explanation for the -1?

Comment: At the bottom of the Firebase Support page, there should be a "Your tech support question status dashboard" section - from there you should get the option to view existing cases and reply. If this isn't working, can you share a screenshot of this section?

Comment: Yeah, it's listed there, but there is no clickable part of the question. It just shows the date, summary, type and status of the question. The status is 'Awaiting your reply'

Comment: @Grimthorr I just updated my question with a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase support will email the account you were logged into when you created the support ticket. You should see an email with a subject like:

"**[*some ticket id*] onMessageReceived() often not called even though it's a data message**"

We're working to make this a bit more clear. Currently, we have this information on the [support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/):

[image]